# System.Net.TcpListener not working on Android/UWP

Tags: c#, android, uwp, tcplistener

Im trying to create a cross platform networking application in C#:

```
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 80);
// [...]
listener.Start();
new Thread(() => {
   Log("Server Started");
   while(true){
      try {
         TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();                    
         Log("Client connected");
         // [...]
         client.Close();
      }
   }
}).Start();
```

It works fine on Win32, however on Android and UWP I cannot get a connection to a client.

I've added the `INTERNET`-permission on android and tried with the `InternetClientServer` and `PrivateNetworkClientServer` capabilities on UWP, but it still won't work.

Comment: In UWP app, where is your client? Whether the client and the server are on the same device? Network communications using an IP loopback address cannot be used for interprocess communication (between two different apps) in a Windows Runtime app since this is restricted by network isolation.

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT The client is another device in the same network.